# Рандом ответ от бота

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Допустим пользователь вводит фразу.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы бот рандомом выбрал ответ?
Например: "да", "нет", "возможно".

Comment: Модуль `random`.

Comment: не выходит так, я пыталась